# Converting Dolar (U$) to Real (R$) and vice-versa

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 inputs to convert from dollar to real and the same fields do the conversion from real to dollar.

I'm having problems typing the value is never correct!

It always ends up increasing a zero or decreasing as you type, I believe it may be because of the mask, how can I solve this?

[Here at Google exactly how it should work.](https://www.google.com/search?q=conversor%20dolar%20real&oq=conver&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j69i60j69i65l3j69i60l2.1623j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)
Or this one: [MelhorCambio](https://www.melhorcambio.com/conversor-de-moeda)

Here my code:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.16/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
```

```js
$('#valorInvest').on('keydown keypress input blur', function(e) {
  $('.dinheiro').mask('#,##0.00', {
    reverse: true
  });
  $('#valorInvestReal').mask('#.##0,00', {
    reverse: true
  });

  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#valorInvestReal').val('');
    cotacao_dollar = Number($('#dollar').val());
    $('.dinheiro').mask('#,##0.00', {
      reverse: true
    });
    dollar = $('#valorInvest').val().replace('U$ ', '');
    dollar = Number(dollar.replace(',', ''));
    convertido = dollar * cotacao_dollar; //
    $('#valorInvestReal').val(Number((convertido).toFixed(2)));

    $('#valorInvestReal').unmask.mask('#.##0,00');

  }, 100);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='dollar' name='dollar' type='hidden' value=''>
<input type="tel" id="valorInvestReal" name="valorInvestReal" placeholder="" class="dinheiro_real font-20 line-height-small bottom-20" autocomplete="new-password">
<input id="valorInvest" name="valorInvest" placeholder="Mínimo 50.00" class="dinheiro" autocomplete="new-password" type="tel" inputmode="numeric" pattern="[0-9]*">
```

Comment: Which mask plugin are you using? can you update your code with plugin script link.

Comment: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.16/jquery.mask.min.js

Comment: how you will get the original price of dollar and real? I mean will you set it static?

Comment: The dollar value I get through the input id = 'dollar' of an Ajax return service.
An ajax returns me and I play that input hiden.

So when you enter U$ 100.00 and you return R$ 531,00
When typing R$ 531,00 he returns me U$ 100.00